# Problem in exporting to MS-Project xml format. Completed work cannot be exported

Tags: xml, project-management, xsd, ms-project

I am Exporting data to ms-project xml file using the mspdi.xsd and I was able to successfully create the xml file and it is opening properly in the MS Project also. 
But I am not able to export the percentage work completed. Following is the generated xml and if we open teh file, we can see all the data except the percentage completed/percentage work complete/ actual work.

Can somebody help me to fix the issue?

following is the generated xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project">
  <UID>105</UID>
  <Name>Last task test</Name>
  <Title>Last task test</Title>
  <Revision>1</Revision>
  <CriticalSlackLimit>0</CriticalSlackLimit>
  <CurrencyDigits>2</CurrencyDigits>
  <Tasks>
    <Task>
      <UID>1698</UID>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>First Task</Name>
      <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-21T09:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-21T17:00:00</Finish>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>57</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>57</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualWork>4</ActualWork>
      <Baseline>
        <Number>0</Number>
        <Start>2010-07-21T00:00:00</Start>
        <Finish>2010-07-31T00:00:00</Finish>
      </Baseline>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>1700</UID>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>Task 1-1</Name>
      <OutlineLevel>2</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-21T09:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-21T12:00:00</Finish>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>67</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>67</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualWork>2</ActualWork>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>1701</UID>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Name>Task 1-2</Name>
      <OutlineLevel>2</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-21T12:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-21T17:00:00</Finish>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>50</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>50</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualWork>2</ActualWork>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>1699</UID>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <Name>Second Task </Name>
      <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-21T09:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-22T10:00:00</Finish>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>50</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>50</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualWork>4</ActualWork>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>1697</UID>
      <ID>5</ID>
      <Name>Fourth Task</Name>
      <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-27T09:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-27T14:00:00</Finish>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>50</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>50</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualWork>4</ActualWork>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>1696</UID>
      <ID>6</ID>
      <Name>Third Task</Name>
      <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-26T09:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-26T14:00:00</Finish>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>100</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>100</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualWork>8</ActualWork>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>1695</UID>
      <ID>7</ID>
      <Name>Fifth Task</Name>
      <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-29T09:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-29T15:20:00</Finish>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>75</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>75</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualWork>12</ActualWork>
    </Task>
  </Tasks>
  <Resources>
    <Resource>
      <UID>446</UID>
      <Name>Resource 1</Name>
      <Group>Permanent</Group>
      <StandardRate>50</StandardRate>
      <StandardRateFormat>2</StandardRateFormat>
    </Resource>
    <Resource>
      <UID>445</UID>
      <Name>Resource 2</Name>
      <Group>Permanent</Group>
      <StandardRate>50</StandardRate>
      <StandardRateFormat>2</StandardRateFormat>
    </Resource>
    <Resource>
      <UID>444</UID>
      <Name>Resource 3</Name>
      <Group>Permanent</Group>
      <StandardRate>62.5</StandardRate>
      <StandardRateFormat>2</StandardRateFormat>
    </Resource>
  </Resources>
  <Assignments>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1698</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>444</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1698</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>446</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1700</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>446</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1701</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>444</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1699</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>444</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1697</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>444</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1697</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>446</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1696</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>445</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1696</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>446</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1695</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>444</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1695</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>445</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>1695</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>446</ResourceUID>
    </Assignment>
  </Assignments>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is solved by setting the following fields

```
<Start>2010-07-19T08:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-19T17:00:00</Finish>
      <Duration>PT8H0M0S</Duration>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <Work>PT8H0M0S</Work>
      <EarlyStart>2010-07-19T08:00:00</EarlyStart>
      <EarlyFinish>2010-07-19T17:00:00</EarlyFinish>
      <LateStart>2010-07-19T08:00:00</LateStart>
      <LateFinish>2010-07-19T17:00:00</LateFinish>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>0</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>0</PercentWorkComplete>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <ActualStart>2010-07-19T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualDuration>PT0H0M0S</ActualDuration>
      <ActualWork>PT0H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <RemainingDuration>PT8H0M0S</RemainingDuration>
      <RemainingWork>PT8H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <ConstraintType>6</ConstraintType>
```

Following is the working xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project">
  <UID>29</UID>
  <Name>PL 202</Name>
  <Title>PL 202</Title>
  <Revision>1</Revision>
  <CriticalSlackLimit>0</CriticalSlackLimit>
  <CurrencyDigits>2</CurrencyDigits>
  <CalendarUID>1</CalendarUID>
  <Calendars>
    <Calendar>
      <UID>1</UID>
      <Name>PL 202</Name>
      <IsBaseCalendar>true</IsBaseCalendar>
      <BaseCalendarUID>-1</BaseCalendarUID>
      <WeekDays>
        <WeekDay>
          <DayType>1</DayType>
          <DayWorking>false</DayWorking>
        </WeekDay>
        <WeekDay>
          <DayType>7</DayType>
          <DayWorking>false</DayWorking>
        </WeekDay>
      </WeekDays>
    </Calendar>
    <Calendar>
      <UID>317</UID>
      <Name>T1</Name>
      <IsBaseCalendar>false</IsBaseCalendar>
      <BaseCalendarUID>1</BaseCalendarUID>
      <WeekDays>
        <WeekDay>
          <DayType>0</DayType>
          <DayWorking>false</DayWorking>
          <TimePeriod>
            <FromDate>2010-08-02T00:00:00</FromDate>
            <ToDate>2010-08-02T23:59:59</ToDate>
          </TimePeriod>
        </WeekDay>
        <WeekDay>
          <DayType>0</DayType>
          <DayWorking>false</DayWorking>
          <TimePeriod>
            <FromDate>2010-08-05T00:00:00</FromDate>
            <ToDate>2010-08-05T23:59:59</ToDate>
          </TimePeriod>
        </WeekDay>
      </WeekDays>
    </Calendar>
    <Calendar>
      <UID>319</UID>
      <Name>T2</Name>
      <IsBaseCalendar>false</IsBaseCalendar>
      <BaseCalendarUID>1</BaseCalendarUID>
      <WeekDays>
        <WeekDay>
          <DayType>0</DayType>
          <DayWorking>false</DayWorking>
          <TimePeriod>
            <FromDate>2010-08-09T00:00:00</FromDate>
            <ToDate>2010-08-09T23:59:59</ToDate>
          </TimePeriod>
        </WeekDay>
        <WeekDay>
          <DayType>0</DayType>
          <DayWorking>false</DayWorking>
          <TimePeriod>
            <FromDate>2010-08-10T00:00:00</FromDate>
            <ToDate>2010-08-10T23:59:59</ToDate>
          </TimePeriod>
        </WeekDay>
      </WeekDays>
    </Calendar>
    <Calendar>
      <UID>321</UID>
      <Name>P2</Name>
      <IsBaseCalendar>false</IsBaseCalendar>
      <BaseCalendarUID>1</BaseCalendarUID>
      <WeekDays>
        <WeekDay>
          <DayType>0</DayType>
          <DayWorking>false</DayWorking>
          <TimePeriod>
            <FromDate>2010-08-02T00:00:00</FromDate>
            <ToDate>2010-08-02T23:59:59</ToDate>
          </TimePeriod>
        </WeekDay>
      </WeekDays>
    </Calendar>
    <Calendar>
      <UID>320</UID>
      <Name>T3</Name>
      <IsBaseCalendar>false</IsBaseCalendar>
      <BaseCalendarUID>1</BaseCalendarUID>
      <WeekDays>
        <WeekDay>
          <DayType>0</DayType>
          <DayWorking>false</DayWorking>
          <TimePeriod>
            <FromDate>2010-08-02T00:00:00</FromDate>
            <ToDate>2010-08-02T23:59:59</ToDate>
          </TimePeriod>
        </WeekDay>
      </WeekDays>
    </Calendar>
  </Calendars>
  <Tasks>
    <Task>
      <UID>318</UID>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>P1</Name>
      <Type>0</Type>
      <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-08-02T08:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</Finish>
      <Duration>PT400H0M0S</Duration>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <Work>PT400H0M0S</Work>
      <EarlyStart>2010-08-02T08:00:00</EarlyStart>
      <EarlyFinish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</EarlyFinish>
      <LateStart>2010-08-02T08:00:00</LateStart>
      <LateFinish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</LateFinish>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>40</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>40</PercentWorkComplete>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <ActualStart>2010-08-02T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualDuration>PT160H0M0S</ActualDuration>
      <ActualWork>PT160H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <RemainingDuration>PT240H0M0S</RemainingDuration>
      <RemainingWork>PT240H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <ConstraintType>6</ConstraintType>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>317</UID>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>T1</Name>
      <Type>0</Type>
      <OutlineLevel>2</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-08-03T08:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</Finish>
      <Duration>PT80H0M0S</Duration>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <Work>PT240H0M0S</Work>
      <EarlyStart>2010-08-03T08:00:00</EarlyStart>
      <EarlyFinish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</EarlyFinish>
      <LateStart>2010-08-03T08:00:00</LateStart>
      <LateFinish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</LateFinish>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>50</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>50</PercentWorkComplete>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <ActualStart>2010-08-03T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualDuration>PT40H0M0S</ActualDuration>
      <ActualWork>PT120H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <RemainingDuration>PT40H0M0S</RemainingDuration>
      <RemainingWork>PT120H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <ConstraintType>6</ConstraintType>
      <CalendarUID>317</CalendarUID>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>319</UID>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Name>T2</Name>
      <Type>0</Type>
      <OutlineLevel>2</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-08-02T08:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</Finish>
      <Duration>PT80H0M0S</Duration>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <Work>PT160H0M0S</Work>
      <EarlyStart>2010-08-02T08:00:00</EarlyStart>
      <EarlyFinish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</EarlyFinish>
      <LateStart>2010-08-02T08:00:00</LateStart>
      <LateFinish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</LateFinish>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>25</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>25</PercentWorkComplete>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <ActualStart>2010-08-02T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualDuration>PT20H0M0S</ActualDuration>
      <ActualWork>PT40H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <RemainingDuration>PT60H0M0S</RemainingDuration>
      <RemainingWork>PT120H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <ConstraintType>6</ConstraintType>
      <CalendarUID>319</CalendarUID>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>321</UID>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <Name>P2</Name>
      <Type>0</Type>
      <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-26T08:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-30T17:00:00</Finish>
      <Duration>PT40H0M0S</Duration>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <Work>PT40H0M0S</Work>
      <EarlyStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</EarlyStart>
      <EarlyFinish>2010-07-30T17:00:00</EarlyFinish>
      <LateStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</LateStart>
      <LateFinish>2010-07-30T17:00:00</LateFinish>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>40</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>40</PercentWorkComplete>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <ActualStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualDuration>PT16H0M0S</ActualDuration>
      <ActualWork>PT16H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <RemainingDuration>PT24H0M0S</RemainingDuration>
      <RemainingWork>PT24H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <ConstraintType>6</ConstraintType>
      <CalendarUID>321</CalendarUID>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>320</UID>
      <ID>5</ID>
      <Name>T3</Name>
      <Type>0</Type>
      <OutlineLevel>2</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-26T08:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-30T17:00:00</Finish>
      <Duration>PT40H0M0S</Duration>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <Work>PT40H0M0S</Work>
      <EarlyStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</EarlyStart>
      <EarlyFinish>2010-07-30T17:00:00</EarlyFinish>
      <LateStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</LateStart>
      <LateFinish>2010-07-30T17:00:00</LateFinish>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>40</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>40</PercentWorkComplete>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <ActualStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualDuration>PT16H0M0S</ActualDuration>
      <ActualWork>PT16H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <RemainingDuration>PT24H0M0S</RemainingDuration>
      <RemainingWork>PT24H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <ConstraintType>6</ConstraintType>
      <CalendarUID>320</CalendarUID>
    </Task>
    <Task>
      <UID>322</UID>
      <ID>6</ID>
      <Name>T4</Name>
      <Type>0</Type>
      <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
      <Start>2010-07-26T08:00:00</Start>
      <Finish>2010-07-26T17:00:00</Finish>
      <Duration>PT8H0M0S</Duration>
      <DurationFormat>5</DurationFormat>
      <Work>PT8H0M0S</Work>
      <EarlyStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</EarlyStart>
      <EarlyFinish>2010-07-26T17:00:00</EarlyFinish>
      <LateStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</LateStart>
      <LateFinish>2010-07-26T17:00:00</LateFinish>
      <FixedCostAccrual>2</FixedCostAccrual>
      <PercentComplete>50</PercentComplete>
      <PercentWorkComplete>50</PercentWorkComplete>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <ActualStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualDuration>PT4H0M0S</ActualDuration>
      <ActualWork>PT4H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <RemainingDuration>PT4H0M0S</RemainingDuration>
      <RemainingWork>PT4H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <ConstraintType>6</ConstraintType>
    </Task>
  </Tasks>
  <Resources>
    <Resource>
      <UID>48</UID>
      <Name>R1</Name>
      <StandardRate>0</StandardRate>
      <StandardRateFormat>2</StandardRateFormat>
    </Resource>
    <Resource>
      <UID>49</UID>
      <Name>R2</Name>
      <StandardRate>0</StandardRate>
      <StandardRateFormat>2</StandardRateFormat>
    </Resource>
    <Resource>
      <UID>50</UID>
      <Name>R3</Name>
      <StandardRate>0</StandardRate>
      <StandardRateFormat>2</StandardRateFormat>
    </Resource>
    <Resource>
      <UID>51</UID>
      <Name>R4</Name>
      <StandardRate>0</StandardRate>
      <StandardRateFormat>2</StandardRateFormat>
    </Resource>
    <Resource>
      <UID>47</UID>
      <Name>R5</Name>
      <StandardRate>0</StandardRate>
      <StandardRateFormat>2</StandardRateFormat>
    </Resource>
    <Resource>
      <UID>52</UID>
      <Name>R6</Name>
      <StandardRate>0</StandardRate>
      <StandardRateFormat>2</StandardRateFormat>
    </Resource>
  </Resources>
  <Assignments>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>317</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>48</ResourceUID>
      <PercentWorkComplete>50</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualStart>2010-08-03T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualWork>PT40H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <Finish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</Finish>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <RegularWork>PT80H0M0S</RegularWork>
      <RemainingWork>PT40H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <Start>2010-08-03T08:00:00</Start>
      <Work>PT80H0M0S</Work>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>317</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>49</ResourceUID>
      <PercentWorkComplete>50</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualStart>2010-08-03T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualWork>PT40H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <Finish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</Finish>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <RegularWork>PT80H0M0S</RegularWork>
      <RemainingWork>PT40H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <Start>2010-08-03T08:00:00</Start>
      <Work>PT80H0M0S</Work>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>317</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>50</ResourceUID>
      <PercentWorkComplete>50</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualStart>2010-08-03T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualWork>PT40H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <Finish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</Finish>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <RegularWork>PT80H0M0S</RegularWork>
      <RemainingWork>PT40H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <Start>2010-08-03T08:00:00</Start>
      <Work>PT80H0M0S</Work>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>319</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>47</ResourceUID>
      <PercentWorkComplete>25</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualStart>2010-08-02T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualWork>PT20H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <Finish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</Finish>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <RegularWork>PT80H0M0S</RegularWork>
      <RemainingWork>PT60H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <Start>2010-08-02T08:00:00</Start>
      <Work>PT80H0M0S</Work>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>319</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>51</ResourceUID>
      <PercentWorkComplete>25</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualStart>2010-08-02T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualWork>PT20H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <Finish>2010-08-17T17:00:00</Finish>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <RegularWork>PT80H0M0S</RegularWork>
      <RemainingWork>PT60H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <Start>2010-08-02T08:00:00</Start>
      <Work>PT80H0M0S</Work>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>321</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>48</ResourceUID>
      <PercentWorkComplete>40</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualWork>PT16H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <Finish>2010-07-30T17:00:00</Finish>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <RegularWork>PT40H0M0S</RegularWork>
      <RemainingWork>PT24H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <Start>2010-07-26T08:00:00</Start>
      <Work>PT40H0M0S</Work>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
      <TaskUID>320</TaskUID>
      <ResourceUID>48</ResourceUID>
      <PercentWorkComplete>40</PercentWorkComplete>
      <ActualStart>2010-07-26T08:00:00</ActualStart>
      <ActualWork>PT16H0M0S</ActualWork>
      <Finish>2010-07-30T17:00:00</Finish>
      <OvertimeWork>PT0H0M0S</OvertimeWork>
      <RegularWork>PT40H0M0S</RegularWork>
      <RemainingWork>PT24H0M0S</RemainingWork>
      <Start>2010-07-26T08:00:00</Start>
      <Work>PT40H0M0S</Work>
    </Assignment>
  </Assignments>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

To see complete progress in MS Project you need to grant these fields in tasks in XML:
PercentComplete
ActualStart
ActualDuration

You can use also:
RemainingDuration

I've found that these fields are mandatory for progress, but didn't managed to make it correctly in my app.